# How to save data in local storage and add to table

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

Here my requirement is submitted data will display in table format and after five submissions records will save in database.

How to save records in local and how to display in table format in jquery or javascript.

My HMTL:

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action="">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored" value="" />

    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="stored" value="" />

    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="stored"></textarea>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savebtn" style="padding: 6px 12px;" id="savebutton"><i class="icon-check-sign" aria-hidden="false"></i> Save </button>
</form>
```

Jquery Code: just i am trying deatils

```
$("button#savebutton").click(function(){
                                var name=$("#name").val();
                                var email=$("#email").val();
                                var message=$("#message").val();    
                           var new_row = "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td><td>" + message + "</td></tr>";
                                    $("table tbody").append(new_row);
                                    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

local storage limited to handle only string key/value pairs you can do like below using JSON.stringify and while getting value JSON.parse

```
var testObject = { {name:"test", email:"xyz@xyz.com", message:"Hello"} };
```

// Put the object into storage

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

Pass this object to data using jquery ajax method and save it find some documentation about jQuery ajax [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this one;

```
<form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action="">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored" value="" />

    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="stored" value="" />

    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="stored"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" class="demo-button" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    $("form").submit(function(e)
    {
        //prevent default form submit
        e.preventDefault();

        //make a blank js object
        var data = {};

        //convert form data to json object
        $("form").serializeArray().map(function(x){data[x.name] = x.value;}); 

        //store thet json object in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("formData",data);

        console.log(data)

        //a blank html string
        var html="";
        p=data;
        for (var key in p) {
            html=html+"<tr>"
            if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                html=html+"<td>"+p[key]+"</td>";
            }
            html=html+"</tr>";
        }

        //finally put html string in a table 
        $("tbody").html(html)

        //now call ajax 
        $.ajax({

              url:backend-api-url,

              method:'get/post',

              data:{
                   name:$('#name').val(),
                   email:$('#email').val(),
                   message:$('#message').val(),
              },

              success:function(data){console.log("done!!!"),}

        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Look I have modified your question a bit just and modified my answer also a bit , what you were trying also 'll work in jQuery but you can try what I did now.

Comment: I got it @koushik

Comment: Great.. glad to hear that :)

Comment: please look at my updated jquery code and tell me how to save details in database by using ajax.

Comment: Now you want a ajax call to save data in database?

Comment: yes :) with all multiple row values. Are you understand my point?

Comment: Yous should have a back end code to do that. Do you have one, may be in PHP or JAVA or C# or any other language?

Comment: i am using java. please tell me how to pass data.